# Import a text file in Deno

Tags: deno

Is there any way to get Deno to **import** a text file (using `import` syntax)?

e.g.:

```
import { body } from "./somefile.txt"

// error: Expected a JavaScript or TypeScript module, 
//   but identified a Unknown module. Importing these
//   types of modules is currently not supported.
//  Specifier: file:///foo/somefile.txt
```

Using tsc this would be configurable but I suspect it might just be impossible in Deno?

Comment: latest deno update mentions "import attributes" which will allow you to import text,blob,wasm etc https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nv2zhic6Jk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deno does not currently support loading plaintext resources using `import` ([static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) or [dynamic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import)).

There is the [import attributes proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-attributes) which allows for importing of different types of *module* resources by using the `with` keyword, but plaintext content is not currently supported.

---

> Using tsc this would be configurable

The TypeScript compiler currently supports resolving JSON resources using `import` syntax via the compiler option [`resolveJsonModule`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#resolveJsonModule), but it does not support plaintext content.

Some bundlers (e.g. [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/), [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development/), [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/)) support the concept of loaders/plugins, which can override the behavior of `import` statements in source code. Node.js offers a similar feature: [module customization hooks](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/module.html#customization-hooks).

On this topic: there is a GitHub issue in the Deno repository: [denoland/deno#8327 — Proposal: Module Loader API](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/8327).

---

The standard method of loading text content in a JavaScript module is to use the [`text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text) method on a response returned by the global [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) method:

```js
const text = await (await fetch("./somefile.txt")).text();
```

Some JS runtimes offer specialized APIs in addition to the above — for example, Deno offers [`Deno.readTextFile`](https://deno.land/api@v1.39.0?s=Deno.readTextFile) and [`Deno.readTextFileSync`](https://deno.land/api@v1.39.0?s=Deno.readTextFileSync):

```js
const text = await Deno.readTextFile("./somefile.txt");
```

Comment: Note: there’s a new PR related to this: [denoland/deno_core#402](https://github.com/denoland/deno_core/pull/402) — I’ll try to keep track of whether it’s merged into Deno and released, and then update this answer.